# Styling ChoiceType element from symfony forms Hello guys

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

Hillo.
I hawe a UserType form:

```
->add('roles', ChoiceType::class, [
                'choices' => ['ROLE_ADMIN' => 'ROLE_ADMIN',
                    'ROLE_MANAGER' => 'ROLE_MANAGER',
                    'ROLE_CUSTOMER' => 'ROLE_CUSTOMER'
                ],
                'choice_attr' => [
                    'ROLE_ADMIN' => ['class' => 'form-check-input'],
                    'ROLE_MANAGER' => ['class' => 'form-check-input'],
                    'ROLE_CUSTOMER' => ['class' => 'form-check-input'],
                ],
                'expanded' => true,
                'multiple' => true,
            ])
```

I wont to styling roles inputs in twig file.

I try add choise atribute

I need get every select from ChoiceType in twig tamplate and styling it.
How can i do this?
P. S.
Sorry for my bed english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To style the choices in your ChoiceType field in Twig, you can iterate over the choices in your template and apply the desired styling.

```
{% for choice in form.roles %}
    <div class="form-check">
        {{ form_widget(choice, {'attr': {'class': 'form-check-input'}}) }}
        {{ form_label(choice) }}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Inform.roles is the ChoiceType field. By iterating over form.roles, you can access each choice individually. form_widget(choice) renders the input element, and form_label(choice) renders the label for each choice. The attr parameter is used to add the desired class for styling purposes.

Make sure to include the necessary CSS classes and styles in your Twig template or linked CSS file to achieve the desired visual styling.